# Getting a null pointer exception while traversing the file system. Java seems to find folders that are hidden, but do not return that they are such

Tags: java

I'm trying to find something on the file system, so I'm digging all through the file system on my computer. However, I'm running into a lot of trouble. Java keeps finding these directories that are, for lack of a better term, super hidden. Meaning, they don't show up in Windows explorer even after setting hidden files to display. As soon as Java hits one of these hidden folders it gets confused and throws a null pointer exception.

Has anyone experienced this, know what these hidden folders are, or how to work around them?

To give an example, the folder that's currently breaking my script is

```
C:\Users\Public\Videos
```

And like I mentioned, this folder is invisible to Explorer. Java seems to not know how to handle it.

As an experiment, I created a `File` from the path, and did a couple of exploratory commands.

```
File mysteryFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Videos") 
System.out.println(mysteryFile.exists())
>>> true 

System.out.println(mysteryFile.isHidden()) 
>>> false    // so confusing! 

Files.isReadable(Paths.get(mysteryFile.getAbsolutePath()))
>>> true
```

Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Windows Explorer can display files with a name different from their actual name. Do you see a `C:\Users\Public\Public Videos` in Explorer?

Comment: Please also include the code that generates the NPE.

Comment: @immibis Oh, yeah, I do see one like that. How should I handle this?

Comment: @user3308744 that depends on what you want to do? How should I know how you should handle it?

Answer (score 1):

Windows is using "English folder names" under the hood. The Folder `C:\Users\Public\Videos` will be renamed by windows explorer according to the language of the operating system.

On a german system for example it would be shown as `C:\Benutzer\Öffentlich\Öffentliche Videos`

Note, that there are A LOT of folders following this behaviour.

But no matter *how* it is shown in Windows Explorer - it's path is `C:\Users\Public\Videos`.

If you hit `WIN-KEY + R` and enter `C:\Users\Public\Videos` - it will open the target directory in question.

Comment: Isnt that a link folder? or am i confusing it with something else?